# How to create a dynamic block from a list of objects?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform variable:

```
variable "volumes" {
  default = [
    {
      "name" : "mnt",
      "value" : "/mnt/cvdupdate/"
    },
    {
      "name" : "efs",
      "value" : "/var"
    },
  ]
}
```

and I am trying to create a dynamic block

```
  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes == "" ? [] : [true]
    content {
      name = volume["name"]
    }
  }
```

but I get an error when I run plan

```
name = volume["name"]
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

The desired output would be:

```
  volume {
    name = "mnt"
  }

  volume {
    name = "efs"
  }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `for_each`, you should use `value`. Also you condition is incorrect. It all should be:

```
  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes == "" ? [] : var.volumes
    content {
      name = volume.value["name"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: get this error 167:       name = volume.value["name"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ volume.value is true
│
│ This value does not have any indices.
╵

Comment: It's a list of maps, so it will require some workarounds.

Comment: @bruvio I update the answer. Apart from missing `.value` the issue was with your condition.

Comment: @MarkoE  Apart from missing `.value`, the issue was with OP's condition. I updated the answer to fix the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `for_each = var.volumes[*]`:

```
dynamic "volume" {
  for_each = var.volumes[*]
  content {
    name = volume.value["name"]
  }
}
```

or:

```
dynamic "volume" {
  for_each = var.volumes[*]
  content {
    name = volume.value.name # <------
  }
}
```

Comment: get this error 167:       name = values(var.volumes.name)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.volumes is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating an `if-else` like condition to pass value to for loop, the condition needs a value to set.  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

- Need to replace `[true]` with `var.volumes` to pass the value.
  `for_each = var.volumes == "" ? [] : var.volumes`
- And, then set the value in the content block with .value to finally set the values to use.

```
    content {
      name = volume.value["name"]
```

The final working code is below as @marcin posted.

```
  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes == "" ? [] : var.volumes
    content {
      name = volume.value["name"]
    }
  }
```